# jQuery get css value of clicked link or tell which link was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got links on my page like this, which when clicked, call jQuery functions. How can I tell if `approve` was clicked or `delete` was clicked. Because I need to do certain things only if accept was clicked, and need not do things if delete were clicked. I cannot change the way those links are named.

```
<i class="icon-accept blue approve"></i>
<i class="icon-reject blue delete"></i>

$('.approve,.delete').on('click', function() {
    if(approved was clicked) {
        console.log('Approve was clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the class using [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
$('.approve,.delete').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('approve')) {
        console.log('Approve was clicked');
    }
});
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/JM6E9/1/)

Alternatively, you can use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$('.approve,.delete').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is('.approve')) {
        console.log('Approve was clicked');
    }
});
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/JM6E9/)

Comment: My mistake, the benchmark I linked to had typos in the markup, [this](http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-stackoverflow/12) suggests the opposite

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `.is()`:

```
if($(this).is('.approve')){}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(element).hasClass('className')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$('.approve,.delete').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('approve')) {
        console.log('Approve was clicked');
    }
});
```